# Making the reading and writing of text files quicker

Tags: python

I have the following code, where I read an input list, split it on its backslash, and then append the variable `evid` to the `evids` array.  Next, I open a file called `evids.txt` and write the `evids` to that file.  How do I speed up/reduce the number of lines in this code? Thanks.

```
evids = []
with open('evid_list.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()
    for i in data:
        evid = i.split('/')[2]
        evids.append(evid)

with open('evids.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in evids:
        f.write("%s" % i)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('evid_list.txt', 'r') as infile, open('evids.txt', 'w') as ofile:
    for line in infile:
        ofile.write('{}\n'.format(line.split('/')[2]))
```